# Spring Boot - No longer calling destroy() on configuration

Tags: spring, groovy, spring-boot

I have an app that was using Spring Boot 1.1.8, and I have a core configuration class (Application.groovy) that had a custom destroy() method implemented that did some tidy up:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAsync(proxyTargetClass=true)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

...

    public void destroy() {
        //do cleanup stuff
    }
}
```

Everything was running fine - I saw the following log message (as well as many other invoke destroy messages):

```
o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'application'
```

I have now upgraded to 1.2.2 of Spring Boot and the destroy method is no longer being invoked - Anyone know why this has stopped being invoked? I still see a few entries in the log of destroy() methods being invoked, but much less than previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the difference in behaviour is rather subtle and it's due to a [change in Spring Framework 4.1.3](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/c1f1cac35956f74302199714db11b36968c1ddcd).

Spring Framework creates a CGLib proxy for each `@Configuration` class and this proxy implements the (internal) `EnhancedConfiguration` interface. Prior to 4.1.3, this interface extended both `DisposableBean` and `BeanFactoryAware`. In 4.1.3 and later it now only extends `BeanFactoryAware`. From the perspective of the Spring container, this meant that your Application class was implementing `DisposableBean` but that it now no longer does.

Rather than relying on an implementation detail of the framework, you should be explicit about the need for `destroy()` to be called. You can either implement `DisposableBean` or annotate your method with `@PreDestroy`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  I did see in the release notes that the move to Boot 1.2 included an upgrade in the underlying Spring version so thought it might be something there.  I had added the DisposableBean interface to my class to fix, but just wanted to understand the change.  Agree on your point about not relying on the framework implementation too.

Answer (score 2):

Something along the class hierarchy changed.  Your class no longer (implicitly) inherits [`DisposableBean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/DisposableBean.html) (where `void destroy()` is it's sole function).  Make your code implement that interface (and put an `@Override` on your method for good measure).  Or add a `@PreDestroy` annotation.  Details are in [the docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-application-exit)

> Each `SpringApplication` will register a shutdown hook with the JVM to ensure that the `ApplicationContext` is closed gracefully on exit. All the standard Spring lifecycle callbacks (such as the `DisposableBean` interface, or the `@PreDestroy` annotation) can be used.

Comment: In `1.1.8` there was also no `DisposableBean` in the hierarchy of the presented class: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.8.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/context/web/SpringBootServletInitializer.html

Comment: @Opal but spring itself contains it since 2.x (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/DisposableBean.html).  So it bet: it was there :)

Comment: How is spring boot constructed? It just wraps spring?

Comment: @Opal springboot applied "educated guesses" on your project and pulls in "known good sets" of their packages.

Comment: Thanks @cfrick - I had fixed it by just adding the DispoableBean interface, but actually just wanted to know if anyone knew what had changed - Testing it shows that the change was at 1.2.0.RELEASE - but I can't see anything either in class heirarchy or the Spring annotations that would have been setting my Application class as a DisposableBean previously